# I wouldn’t take too long thinking about it, if I were you

Tags: meaning

*I wouldn’t take too long thinking about it, if I were you.*

This sentence comes from the movie Once Upon a Time in the West. Although I think I understand the meaning (I wouldn’t hesitate to do it, if I were you) the construction seems to me to be odd. Is "take thinking" some sort of the idiom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is "take too long".  Here is an example in another context

> I took too long planning my essay, so I ran out of time in the examination.

Here is is put into a conditional sentence that is used to give advice

> I wouldn't drink the milk, if I were you.  It has gone bad.

The impression is slightly sinster.  The speaker says you should make a decision quickly, with an implied threat or warning if the person takes too long.

Comment: There is an element of sarcasm, and the threat does not have to be one made by the speaker. I might say "I wouldn't take too long thinking about leaving the building" if it were on fire.